# Restoring Win7 from System Image. Will external HDD be affected?

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-7-restore

I want to restore windows 7 using a system image I created a while back. The image is located on my external HDD and my question is will the contents of my external HDD be deleted or the drive formatted as a whole? I ask because the external HDD contains backups of my personal files and I don't want to lose them.

The part of the process which makes me think my external HDD might be re-formatted is when it says:

> Select this to delete any existing partitions and reformat all disks on this computer to match the layout of the system image.

Here is a screenshot to better illustrate what I'm talking about:
http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/8restore.png

Comment: Have you selected a target at that point?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean by target? All I have done so far is select the system image which is on my external HDD.

Comment: Well first the external drive can't be changed because it has the image on it.  If the drive were to be changed the image would be lost.  The answer to my question is, no the target drive, has not been selected.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the 'Exclude disks' button there to make sure that it's not going to mess with your external drive.